# Set interval for Automatic (Delayed Start) Windows Services

Tags: windows, windows-services, windows-server-2008-r2

I am working on Windows Server 2008 R2. I need to change the delayed start time, that is used in automatic delayed start mode, to 5 mins.

Any pointer as how to do this?

Comment: Explain why you want this. Windows Services with startup type Automatic (Delayed Start) have a fixed delay. The easiest way would be to let your application wait for five minutes after starting before doing any work, but please just explain why you need this. There may be better approaches.

Comment: My application has a requirement that it should start after 10 mins of start of the system(boot) and hence I need to set this delay time to 10 mins.

Comment: _"It's a requirement"_ is no reason. _Why_ does your application need to wait for ten minutes? Anyway if you don't want to elaborate, just use `Thread.Sleep()`.

Comment: Either way you cannot set the delay time for an individual service, there is a global registry setting but it will affect all delayed start services

Comment: Alex, can you please let me know the global registry setting that can be used to set this.

Comment: @CodeCaster People may need this for closed-source third-party applications for specific reasons.

Comment: @Panzer no, that still makes no sense. Why would third-party software be dependent on a N-minute delay in starting your service? You really shouldn't want this, but if you must, workarounds have been mentioned in the comments.

Comment: @CodeCaster I mean, if it's not your service, but theirs, and there's a race condition in it that people are aware of.  I should have said "services" instead of "applications" in the last comment.

Comment: @Panzer this is Stack Overflow, it's about programming. If you want to fix a buggy piece of third-party software by changing system parameters, it's off-topic for SO and other approaches such as the one suggested may be valid. How to set the delay for "Delayed Start" services is well-documented, for example on [SuperUser.com](http://superuser.com/questions/284698/how-much-time-a-delayed-service-waits-to-start).

Answer (score -1):

When the startup type of the service is set to "Automatic (Delayed start)", the value of DelayedAutostart is set to 1
           **HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\\DelayedAutostart**

To increase the default delay of 120 seconds, right click the registry key and add new key AutoStartDelay (DWORD (32-bit)

```
      **HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\<service name>\AutoStartDelay**
```

Its value can be set to decimal 240 for example.

Comment: AutoStartDelay cannot be set for individual services, it is a global setting in HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Control. It is also in milliseconds.